# How do I get a list of links on a web page categorized according to whether no-follow tag is present or not?

Tags: python, web-crawler

The following code that I have gets a list of all links on a web page. I would like to annotate them according to whether they are nofollow links or not. How do I go about doing that?

```
import httplib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

class Extractor():

def get_links(self, url):

    http = httplib2.Http()
    response, content = http.request(url)

    links=[]

    for link in BeautifulSoup(content).find_all('a', href=True):
        links.append(link['href'])

return links


url = 'https://www.challies.com/al-la-carte'

myextractor = Extractor()

links = myextractor.get_links(url)

for link in links:
  print(link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it just the way you get the `href` attribute, but just for the `rel`:

```
link.get('rel')
```

###### Example

Cause question and expected output is not that clear, this example extracts both information and store them in a list of dicts - feel free adjusting it for your needs:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.challies.com'
page = requests.get(url).text
data=[]
for link in BeautifulSoup(page).select('a[href]'):
        data.append({
            'link':link.get('href'),
            'rel':link.get('rel')
        })
data
```

###### Output

```
[...,
{'link': 'https://twitter.com/challies',
  'rel': ['external', 'noopener', 'noreferrer']},
 {'link': '/contact', 'rel': None},
 {'link': 'https://www.patreon.com/challies',
  'rel': ['external', 'noopener', 'noreferrer']},
 {'link': 'https://www.challies.com/tag/dating/', 'rel': None},
 {'link': 'https://www.challies.com/tag/prayer/', 'rel': None},
 {'link': 'https://www.challies.com/tag/worship/', 'rel': None},
 {'link': 'https://www.challies.com/category/resources/',
  'rel': ['category', 'tag']},
 {'link': 'https://www.challies.com/resources/what-is-a-woman/',
  'rel': ['bookmark']},
 {'link': 'https://www.challies.com/resources/what-is-a-woman/',
  'rel': ['bookmark']},
 {'link': 'https://www.challies.com/resources/what-is-a-woman/',
  'rel': ['bookmark']},
 {'link': 'https://www.challies.com/resources/what-is-a-woman/', 'rel': None},
 {'link': 'https://www.challies.com/category/a-la-carte/',
  'rel': ['category', 'tag']},...]
```